# Failed to connect to server: The requested address is a broadcast address, but the appropriate flag was not set

Tags: windows-7, ip, dhcp

My server IP address starts with 128.xxx.xxx.xxx and my laptop gets its address as a DHCP and is of the for 10.254.xxx.xxx
I configured the server to look for my laptop and when I start the server it give a message that it is listening.  I configured the client on the laptop to connect to the server and when I apply the settings it prints the message:
connecting to '128.xxx.xxx.xxx'   followed the the failed to connect message in the title.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem before and it was unrelated to the error message displayed - something was blocking the port. Try disabling all firewalls and check if something else is listening on needed port (probably not since you got the server to bind a socket correctly).